# PHP $_POST[] not void after redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I'm opening myself to honest critizism and sugggestions.

The issue is with the function $_POST[void] being valid after a redirect. Quotes.add.php is a form that directs to quotes.done.php, submitted to mysql and redirected back to quotes.add.php with an echo $msg and reset to be filled out again.
Is header(); the best method in this case?

quotes.done.php

```
else{
    include 'data.php';
    $query = "INSERT INTO quotes (`id`, `quotes`, `artist`, `date`) VALUES ('null', '$_POST[text]', '$_POST[artist]', 'null')"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $_POST['void'] = "$_POST[artist] Was Added Successfully to database";   
    unset ($_POST['artist']);       

    //var_dump($_POST['void']);
    //exit;             
    header ("location: quotes.add.php");
    exit;   
}
```

quotes.add.php

```
if (isset($_POST['void'])) {
    $msg = $_POST['void'];  
}else{
    $msg = "Please insert artist";      
}
```

Comment: A header()-based redirect cause the browser to issue a GET request on the URL being redirected to. POST values are **NOT** sent when redirecting. As well, any changes you make to the _POST array (as in your success message) are not pasted into a form or a redirect. It's a useless operation.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework that might persist the $_POST array through sessions? Are you accessing it anywhere else?

Comment: Shivers shivers... tired of explaining the vulnerabilities of these kind of code. :/

Comment: Bit off topic but You'll want to put some security in place on that mysql query!

Comment: There seems no reason to add security when I'm only doing personal operations to understand php functionality. There's only so much you can learn from books.

Comment: also seriously consider using a MVC framework like http://www.codeigniter.com

Comment: Thanks Herr Kaleun! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a redirect i think you have to use $_SESSION. 
I'd do:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['msg'] =  "$_POST[artist] Was Added Successfully to database";
header ("location: quotes.add.php");
exit;
```

and then

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    $msg = $_SESSION['msg'];  
    unset($_SESSION['msg'];
}else{
    $msg = "Please insert artist";      
}
```

Comment: To add to your answer, you need `session_start()` both when setting and reading sessions.

Comment: why is it that a page refresh $_POST[] can be true even after unset but $_SESSION[] stays false? Hm, research needs to be done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is the clean, proper, and secure way to do it:

**quotes.done.php**

```
<?php
else{
    include 'data.php';

    // escape the input, to avoid SQL injection
    $text   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
    $artist =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['artist']);

    $query  = "INSERT INTO quotes (`id`, `quotes`, `artist`, `date`) VALUES ('null', '{$text}', '{$artist}', 'null')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // always set your variables to a default value
    $success = false;

    // did the query execute successfully?
    if($result){
        $success = true;
    }

    header('Location: quotes.add.php?result=addedquote&amp;artist='.urlencode($_POST['artist']).'&amp;success='.urlencode($success));
    exit;
}
?>
```

**quotes.add.php**

```
<?php
$msg = '';
if(isset($_GET['result']) && $_GET['result'] == 'addedquote') {
    $artist     =   htmlentities(urldecode($_GET['artist']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
    $success    =   (bool) urldecode($_GET['success']);
    if($success){
        $msg = "$artist Was Added Successfully to database";
    } else{
        $msg = "Failed to Add $artist to database";
    }
} else{
    $msg = "Please insert artist";      
}
?>
```

A couple of things for you to note here:

1. If you are not using a wrapper for running your db queries with prepared parameterized statements, you should use at least `mysql_real_escape_string()` to remove the nasty stuff in order to prevent SQL injection.
2. As noted by others `header()` will do a `GET` request, hence why you are not getting the `$_POST[void]` on the page you are redirecting. That's why you will use variables on your url to transfer them to the redirected page, and then fetch them with `$_GET`.
3. `$_POST[somename]` and `$_POST['somename']` are two different things. They will work, because PHP will try to see if there is a constant named `somename`, if there isn't one, you are lucky, but if there is one, then all sky falls down.

Comment: Shef, I appreciate your patience. Your comments have been noted and hopefully I won't be making the same mistakes in future questions.

Comment: @crash_cource: Sure. I didn't feel like jumping in and explaining, because the code was a little bit "messed", but I saw no one else noting these things, so I simply had to. :) Keep trying and learning, but before you deploy something, ask someone you trust with enough experience to do at least a quick audit for security issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the $_POST variables, don't redirect. A redirect causes the client's browser to re-request the page with only $_GET params.

Save the record to the database. Get the new record ID, redirect to a page and pass in the ID. Then use the ID to fetch and display the record.

Comment: it works, but you have an extra query, he only needs to pass a msg.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting will not POST a value to the page. You could use session or GET.

```
$message = urlencode("$_POST[artist] Was Added Successfully to database");
header ("location: quotes.add.php?message=" . $message);
```

On your quotes.add.php page

```
echo $_GET['message'];
```